# How to convert array of char into array of int in C Programming?

Tags: arrays, c, type-conversion

```c
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 5 

void convert ( char parray[] ,int array[] )

{

    int i; 
    for (i=0; i< LENGTH; i++)
    {
        array[i] = atoi(&parray[i]);
        printf(" The converted array is %d\n" , array[i]);
    }
}

int main ()

{

    char parray[LENGTH] = { '7', '1', '4','5' ,'2'};

    int iarray[LENGTH];

    convert(parray, iarray);
}
```

******** Output *********

```
The converted array is 71452

The converted array is 1452

The converted array is 452

The converted array is 52

The converted array is 2

But I want the following output like this

The converted array is 7

The converted array is 1

The converted array is 4

The converted array is 5

The converted array is 2
```

It should store value of 7 in `array[0]` , 1 in `array[1]` !!!! Please help

Comment: I tried it gives me error Mr.LSerni : error: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   array[i] = atoi(parray[i]);

Comment: 1) Strings need to be null terminated. 2) atoi translates the whole string to an integer, not digit by digit.

Comment: Sorry, I had not looked carefully.  I thought it was an array of a different nature. The correct answer has already been given by MikeCAT.

Comment: Thank you Mr.LSerni and Mr.Lundin for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing single characters with character *strings*. The latter are sequences of characters (arrays) terminated with a `nul` (zero value) character, and that is what the `atoi` function expects as its input.

To convert a *single* character digit to its numerical value, you just need to subtract the value of the zero digit (`'0'`) from that character's value (the values of the numerical digits are *guaranteed* by the Standard to be contiguous).

So, rather than:

```c
array[i] = atoi(&parray[i]);
```

use:

```c
array[i] = parray[i] - '0'; // Will work if (and only if) parray[i] is a digit.
```

---

What is happening in your code is that (by chance) there is a zero byte immediately after the end of your 5-character array (but you can **not** rely on this), so each `atoi(&parray[i])` call is passing a character string starting with, respectively, the `'7'`, `'1'`, `'5'`, `'4'` and `'2'` characters, and ending only after the `'2'`. Thus, you are getting values that represent the numbers formed by the concatenation of your individual array digits. But I repeat: *you cannot rely on there being a zero-value character after your array*!

Comment: char parray[LENGTH] = { '-7', '1', '4','5' ,'2'}; What I have multiple characters like -7 and store it in array [0] = -7 ! Its giving error when I give -7 in parray. error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]

Comment: @AnasMunir I *think* that using `'-7'` to initialize a `char` variable puts you in undefined behaviour territory. On my system, that represents an `int` constant of value `11575` but how that is then interpreted as a `char` will likely vary.

Comment: Basically I am asking that is there a way to convert multiple characters like -7. My program only works for single characters like 1 4 9. But not for 14 or -7. Is there a way I can modify my function in order to convert multiple characters as well ? Mr.Adrian

Comment: @AnasMunir You would need to declare your `parray` as an array of strings (`const char* parray[] = {"-7", "1", "4", "5", "2"};`  - even the 'single digit' values will be arrays of 2 characters, because of the added nul-terminator) and then call `atoi(parray[i])` (no `&` symbol) on each of those strings.

Comment: When I am declaring char *parray[] = = { '-7', '1', '4','5' ,'2'}                          Its giving 2 errors mainly :                                                                      error 1 : multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]
char* parray[LENGTH] = { '-7', '1', '4','5' ,'2'};                                         error 2:  error: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @Anas - Use **double** quotes for *string* literals, single quotes for single character literals. `'2'` is a character (actually, an `int`); `"2"` is a string consisting of the digit, `2` and a nul terminator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233896/discussion-between-anas-munir-and-adrian-mole).

Answer (score 4):

[`atoi()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) is for converting strings (sequences of characters terminated by a null-character) to integers. To convert single character to an integer, you can subtract `'0'` (the character code of `0`) from the character because it is guaranteed in C specification that character codes for decimal digits are continuous.

```
void convert ( char parray[] ,int array[] )

{

    int i; 
    for (i=0; i< LENGTH; i++)
    {
        array[i] = parray[i] - '0';
        printf(" The converted array is %d\n" , array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that 60k user should look for the dupe first.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Mike for your time it actually worked out perfectly when I tested.

Comment: @0___________ Although I can understand why you selected that dupe target (and I'm not going to dispute it), note that it does *not* address the use of the `atoi` function in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
array[i] = atoi(&parray[i]);
```

invokes undefined behavior because the character array `parray` does not contain a string: a sequence of characters terminated with the zero character '`\0'`. And the function `atoi` expects a string as its argument.

Instead you could write

```
array[i] = parray[i] - '0';
```

Character `'0'` through up to `'9'` have an increased by 1 sequence of codes. So for example if to write '3' - '0' you will get the integer number `3`.

Comment: char parray[LENGTH] = { '-7', '1', '4','5' ,'2'}; What I have multiple characters like -7 and store it in array [0] = -7  Its giving error when I give -7 in parray. error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]

Comment: @AnasMunir It is a multibyte character. Its representation is implementation defined.